# Why do I get a syntax error while I am using varbinary(max) in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I was trying to use varbinary(max) for my image data type, but I always get sytax error near "max) ...",

**here is my sql code**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ShopingSite;

USE ShopingSite;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Category (
    C_id int NOT NULL,
    C_name varchar(30),
    PRIMARY KEY(C_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product (
    P_id int NOT NULL,
    P_name varchar(30),
    C_id int,
    image varbinary(max),
    PRIMARY KEY(P_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (C_id) REFERENCES Category(C_id)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum size of a `varbinary` column depends on remaining table row space (65535 bytes) shared among all columns.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product (
    P_id int NOT NULL,
    P_name varchar(30),
    C_id int,
    image varbinary(65000),
    PRIMARY KEY(P_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (C_id) REFERENCES Category(C_id)
);
```

If all the rows add up to 535 bytes (the value is an example), then the above query will work.